# Attaching a file to an appointment request not showing up in CRM 2013

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013, outlook-2013

I created an appointment within Outlook 2013, with an attached file. I then send the appt request, making sure it's tracked. Synchronized outlook with CRM 2013 version.

Within CRM, the appointment is available linked to contact but it does not have the attached file,

Is this expected of Dynamics CRM **2013** for Outlook?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attachments for appointments are not synchronized with CRM when tracked with CRM 2013 for Outlook, but this capability has been added with CRM 2015 for Outlook or later according to Microsoft: [Track Outlook appointments in Dynamics 365 for Outlook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/outlook-addin/user-guide/track-outlook-appointments)

> If you’re using Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2015 for Outlook or later, you
>   can also synchronize appointment attachments if your system
>   administrator has enabled this capability.

Comment: Thank you. This helps alot.